# Set role to a guest user, it's possible?

Tags: user-roles

I've been questioning for quite a time if it's possible to grant access of a user role to a guest/visitor and I haven't found a proper answer.

Can you guys give me a light spot in the end of that tunnel?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You could simple check against `is_user_logged_in()`. If that returns false, they're a guest.